# best practice to deploy aws lambda to another region using cloud9

Tags: python, bash, amazon-ec2, aws-lambda, aws-cloud9

The problem: lambda can't use an s3 trigger hosted in London if I deploy the lambda in Ireland. Ideally I would just launch a cloud9 instance in London but this service is not yet available in London.

Cloud9 is great for testing and developing a lambda which needs to interact with other aws services, code requiring other aws services developed on a local system needs to be changed for deployment which is obviously not ideal. Hence why I would rather develop using the cloud9 IDE.

As a workaround I've been developing on and EC2 instance based in Ireland, then I have a script with copies the essential files for a lambda and zips it up and sends it to an s3 bucket. I can then generate a lambda anywhere and import the zip from an s3 bucket.

However, this seems very cumbersome, there must be a better way?

Here is code examples (1) lambda

```
import json
import re
import boto3
import numpy    

s3 = boto3.client('s3')  

def lambda_handler(event, context):
    """DO SOMETHING"""

    return {
        'statusCode': 200,
        'body': json.dumps('lambda run sucessfully')
    }
```

(2) python script to package lambda (which calls a bash script to zip) and send it to an s3:

```
import os
import sys
import boto3
import subprocess


def package_lambda(packageName, pathToFiles):
    """Calls a bash script which packages the lambda function and 
        its dependencies into a zip"""

    print('calling bash script')
    subprocess.check_call(['/home/ec2-user/environment/shell_scripts/package_lambda.sh', packageName, pathToFiles])
    print('bash script finished')

    return

def moveFileToBucket(myfile, bucket):
    """pushes a file from the local system to an s3 bucket"""

    if os.path.exists(myfile):
        s3 = boto3.client('s3')
        key=str(myfile).split('/')[-1]
        s3.upload_file(myfile, bucket, key)
        print("{} uploaded sucessfully".format(myfile))
    else:
        raise Exception('No file named: '+myfile)

    return


if __name__=='__main__':
    package_lambda(sys.argv[1], sys.argv[2])
    moveFileToBucket(sys.argv[3], sys.argv[4])
```

(3) bash script called by python script to zip up lambda:

```
#!/bin/bash

packageName=$1
pathToFiles=$2

ext1="_package"

# print path incase debuggin is needed
ls -lt $pathToFiles

# set variables
lambda=$pathToFiles/$packageName/$packageName/lambda_function.py
lambda_packages=$pathToFiles/$packageName/

# Remove any previous copies of the package
rm -r $pathToFiles/$packageName$ext1

# print paths for logging/debuggin purposes
ls $lambda
ls $lambda_packages

# copy the lambda
cp -r $lambda_packages $pathToFiles/$packageName$ext1
# move the lambda for packaging
cp $lambda $pathToFiles/$packageName$ext1/lambda_function.py

# remove directories and files which are not needed for zip
rm -r  $pathToFiles/$packageName$ext1/venv
rm -r  $pathToFiles/$packageName$ext1/$packageName
rm $pathToFiles/$packageName$ext1/__init__.py
rm $pathToFiles/$packageName$ext1/template.yaml
rm $pathToFiles/$packageName$ext1/requirements.txt

# move into the package copy to zip
cd $pathToFiles/$packageName$ext1
zip -r ../lambda_function.zip *
```

Then invoke the packaging scrip from the command line to send it to a bucket so it can be deployed anywhere.

```
python3 /home/ec2-user/environment/pythonScripts/packageAndMoveFileToBucket.py myLambdaName /home/ec2-user/environment/pythonLambdaRepo /home/ec2-user/environment/pythonLambdaRepo/lambda_function.zip bucketForLambdas
```

It may be the case that the community feels this is a perfectly good method to solve this problem? But it feels a bit cumbersome and I haven't seen any documentation from Amazon or elsewhere suggesting a 'better' way? Any feedback would be great?

Comment: Not sure if this helps, but once you deploy the function in one region, you don't need to repackage it to deploy it elsewhere... the [`GetFunction`](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/lambda/latest/dg/API_GetFunction.html) action in the Lambda API and its CLI equivalent [`aws lambda get-function`](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/cli/latest/reference/lambda/get-function.html) gives you a pre-signed URL for downloading the deployment package, along with the rest of the function configuration.

Comment: This sounds potentially like what I'm looking for, its quite complicated to implement though from a quick read here: https://docs.aws.amazon.com/cli/latest/reference/lambda/get-function.html if you have time could you show a step by step example? No worries if not, thanks for the pointer

Answer (score 0):

It sounds like you want to change the AWS Region that the AWS Cloud9 IDE is currently set to and then deploy your AWS Lambda function to that new Region. If so, see the following instructions, which describe how to change the Region: https://docs.aws.amazon.com/cloud9/latest/user-guide/lambda-functions.html#lambda-functions-prepare-region

Comment: That would be ideal, however cloud9 doesn't seem to be available in London yet which is where I need to deploy the lambda. The trigger we need to launch the lambda is based in London and you can't (yet) trigger lambdas in different regions to where an s3 is hosted. Unless I missed something?